# Toshiba Drive Sleeping - SDPARM

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk, arm

My toshiba 1tb external keeps going to sleep and I can't seem to locate anything that resembles a standby parameter. Does anyone know a way to get this drive to quit sleeping? Here is the output of `sdparm -a /dev/sdc`:

```
    sudo sdparm -a /dev/sdc
    /dev/sdc: TOSHIBA   External USB 3.0  0001
Read write error recovery mode page:
  AWRE        1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  0]
  ARRE        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  TB          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  RC          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EER         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  PER         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DTE         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DCR         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  RRC         3  [cha: n, def:  3, sav:  0]
  COR_S       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  HOC         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DSOC        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  LBPERE      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  WRC         3  [cha: n, def:  3, sav:  0]
  RTL         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
Caching (SBC) mode page:
  IC          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  ABPF        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  CAP         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DISC        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  SIZE        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  WCE         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  MF          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  RCD         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DRRP        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  WRP         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DPTL        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  MIPF        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  MAPF        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  MAPFC       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  FSW         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  LBCSS       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DRA         1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  0]
  NV_DIS      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  NCS         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  CSS         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
Informational exceptions control mode page:
  PERF        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EBF         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EWASC       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  DEXCPT      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  TEST        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EBACKERR    0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  LOGERR      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  MRIE        6  [cha: n, def:  6, sav:  0]
  INTT        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
Background control (SBC) mode page:
  S_L_FULL    0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  LOWIR       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EN_BMS      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  EN_PS       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
  BMS_I       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
Logical block provisioning (SBC) mode page:
  SITUA       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]
```

The following appears to be working, I'll update this question if the drive does indeed sleep again.

```
sudo hdparm --prefer-ata12 -S 0 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting standby to 0 (off)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 01 00 50 40 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Try looking through  power-management options

Comment: It is a powersaving feature of the disk/enclosure. I solved it once by setting up a cron job that accesses the drive every so many minutes, preventing it to spin down.